# How to test raw loaded data with React

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, raw-data

I need to load javascript raw data from a .js file. I have this helper to do such thing:

```js
import {
  reduceFunctionGarbage
} from "./reduce-function-garbage";

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
export const getRawChallenge = num =>
  reduceFunctionGarbage(require(`!raw-loader!../challenges/${num}.js`));
```

When I try to run the tests, I get the following error:

[image: Code error]

How can I test a file which imports RAW data?
I've tried with **jest-raw-loader** (https://github.com/keplersj/jest-raw-loader) but it didn't work for me.

Anyone who could point me to the right direction?

Comment: Did you try this ? 
`npm install raw-loader --save-dev`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can mock your files like this

```
jest.mock(`!raw-loader!../challenges/4.js`, () => 'hello-raw-data');
```

in case they don't exists you can provide `{ virtual: true }`

```
jest.mock(`!raw-loader!../challenges/4.js`, () => 'hello-raw-data', {
  virtual: true,
});
```

[working example](https://repl.it/repls/FlamboyantImmaculateCharacter)